# Bot Framework sending OPTIONS message

Tags: botframework, bots, azure-bot-service

Recently, I have been getting 405 response messages logged in Application Insights from the bot framework relating to "OPTIONS" message being sent.

How should my service be responding to these?

Who is making these requests?

Answer (score 2):

Sorry if you saw my previous answer; it was completely off base so I deleted it in shame.

The requests you mention are made by Azure when navigating to WebChat or the Settings tab. To allow the call, you can create a custom bot auth class:

```
 public class CustomBotAuthenticationAttribute : BotAuthentication
    {
        public override Task OnActionExecutingAsync(HttpActionContext actionContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            if (actionContext.Request.Method.Method == "OPTIONS") // allow OPTIONS through, and do not authenticate
                return Task.CompletedTask;

            return base.OnActionExecutingAsync(actionContext, cancellationToken);
        }
    }
```

Then, in the MessagesController:

```
[CustomBotAuthentication] // Change from [BotAuthentication]
public class MessagesController : ApiController
{

    public HttpResponseMessage Options() // handle options
    {
        return new HttpResponseMessage { StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK };
    }

    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post([FromBody]Activity activity)
```

Comment: Thank you! That makes much sense!

Comment: How would you do this within Bot Framework v4, as the problem has resurfaced after moving to v4.